# Security in Meteor methods - should I pass an object or just the id to the server?

Tags: meteor

In my Meteor method that will update an object stored in a collection, should I pass the complete object to the server, or just the id and fetch the object on the server?

```
Meteor.methods({
    myMethodOne: function (invitation) {
         // do something with invitation, send out email etc.
    },

    myMethodTwo: function (invId) {
         var invitation = Invitations.findOne({_id: invId});
         // check state, ownership etc. on invitation
         // then, update invitation, send out an email, etc.
    } 
});
```

For security reasons, I assume myMethodTwo should be preferred, so I can check ownership of the invitation etc. - but is there some Meteor magic I can use to make validating the ownership, state etc. of the object on the server easier, (semi-)automatic?

Comment: have you checked `allow/deny` functions? I feel that is the better place to check ownership http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Comment: I did, but since I need to do additional stuff (like sending out an email, if the state of an invitation has changed) on the server, I want to use methods.

Comment: oh okay then I feel second method is better, less data tiny fast

Comment: The first method passes the invitation itself, which requires `check`ing it. The second method fetches the invitation from a collection... But how did it get to this collection? It requires an insertion, which requires `check`ing. Which one is the best is irrelevant, both have the same necessities.

Comment: @Kyll : the invitation was created in another method, the client cannot create invitations.

So, I guess the underlaying question becomes: Is there a best practice in Meteor to do programmatic constraints on Collection item modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the ID and fetch the object on the server.
The key security principle here is:

- Don't trust user input

So [check all parameters passed by the client](http://justmeteor.com/blog/meteor-security-fundamentals/), and minimize what they need to pass.  Don't let them pass the whole object, which you will have to ensure matches what is in the database anyway, just the id.  This requires less input validation, and results in less edge cases that increase the attack surface of your api.

[There is 'Meteor Magic' for validating ownership of the object: this.userId](http://joshowens.me/meteor-security-201/).  Never rely on a userId passed from the client.

A slight modification to your myMethodTwo func could address both the above like this:

```
myMethodTwo: function (invId) {
  var invitation = Invitations.findOne({_id: invId, owner: this.userId});
  if (typeof(invitation) === 'undefined'){
    throw new Meteor.Error("User has no object with that id",
                           "Object does not exist or user is not owner");
  }
  // check state, 
  // then, update invitation, send out an email, etc.
}
```

State is going to be application specific, don't expect any pre built magic there.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I have removed my downvote. Be careful, as if you first post a very short answer, you may get downvotes that will not be removed later because the downvoter won't see your edit.